# Javascript querystring parameter flashvar with swfobject

Tags: javascript, swfobject, flashvars, querystringparameter

With javascript functions in the head section of a webpage, I've been able to parse the querystring and send that as a flashvar to an swf, constructing the object embed with one of the JS functions like so:

...

```
function writeFlash() {
 var width = '1024'
 var height = '500'
 var src = 'j.swf'
 var queries = 'im='+QueryString('im')+'.jpg'
 var l1 = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'">;'
 var l2 = '<param name="movie" value="'+src+'" />;'
 var l6 = '<param name="flashvars" value="'+queries+'" />;'
 var l3 = '<param name="quality" value="high" />;'
 var l4 = '<embed src="'+src+queries+'" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'"></embed>;'
 var l5 = '</object>'
 document.write(l1+l2+l6+l3+l4+l5)
}
```

....

In the body of the page, I call that function to open the swf like this.

...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
writeFlash();
-->
</script>
```

...

I'm tring to use SWFobject instead (which I am also using somewhere else to load JW player).   When I try to translate my embed to swfobject code I don't manage to shuffle the flashvar through in multiple ways I've tried, please help.

Answer (score 0):

But why do that when in flash you can just do `ExternalInterface.call("eval", "document.location.search")`

Also don't do with swfobject. Look **static publishing** which is much cleaner and better for new browsers.

Here is an example of that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.115", "expressInstall.swf");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="780" height="420">
        <param name="movie" value="myContent.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myContent.swf" width="780" height="420">
        <!--<![endif]-->
          <p>Alternative content</p>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
      </object>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would this do it?       param name="movie" value="myContentswf'+document.location.search+'"

Comment: No this is just a sample. In your flash file you still need to do what I did by calling eval(document.location.search) to return to you the query string. There is no reason to pass it in when flash can fetch it.